# Unzip specific files in a ARR file within a Tar.gz

Tags: unix, tar, aar

i'am currently trying to unzip some specific files within a ARR file. This ARR file is within a tar.gz file.
Is it possible to unzip these files without a intermediate step/One liner. Its important that the first tar.gz will not be unpacked.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
gzip -dc input_file.tar.gz|tar xf - path/to/file/you/want/to/extract
```

This decompress and untar the archive in memory and have advantage of run faster.